# Comma after introductory discourse marker

Tags: punctuation, commas, sentence-starts, filler-words

When beginning a sentence with "well", do you put a comma after it?

> - Well, you know I was wrong.
> - Well you know I was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Well water does not contain chlorine. In the previous sentence the word in question is used to modify the subject of the sentence, water.  But, when *well* is an expletive, it is parenthetical and needs the comma.

Comment: well said, sir.

Comment: Thank you! I transcribe and my boss keeps removing the commas that follow "well" at the beginning of a sentence.....

Comment: I'd say most would omit it nowadays in << Well I never! >> (most of those who would still use this).